# (rassoc) returns NIL on nested list when (find) does not

Tags: common-lisp, ansi-common-lisp

I want to perform `(rassoc)` over a nested list like this:

```
(setq mlist
   (list (list (cons "A"  0)
               (make-hash-table))
         (list (cons "B"  1)
               (make-hash-table))))
```

Oddly enough, `(find)` and `(assoc)` work as expected, but `(rassoc)` fails.

```
(format t "~A~%" (assoc "A" mlist :key #'car :test #'equal))
(format t "~A~%" (find 0 mlist :key #'cdar :test #'equal))
(format t "~A~%" (rassoc 0 mlist :key #'car :test #'equal))
```

The [Common Lisp HyperSpec](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_rassoccm__assoc-if-not.html) states:

> The expressions
>
> `(rassoc item list :test fn)`
>
> and
>
> `(find item list :test fn :key #'cdr)`
>
> are equivalent in meaning, except when the item is `nil` nd `nil` appears
> in place of a pair in the alist. See the function assoc.

So, given this, I wonder, is this a bug or am I just using `(rassoc)` incorrectly? I'm using sbcl 2.4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `rassoc` incorrectly.  `rassoc` looks at the `cdr`s of the entries in an alist, skipping `nil` entries, and compares them (or the result of applying the key function to them) with what you want.

The `cdr`s of the entries in your list are single-element lists containing a hashtable, with a key of `#'car` you will be comparing against those hashtables.

You shouldn't be using `rassoc` at all if what you want to do is to check against the second element of the `car`s of the alist.  Instead use `assoc` with an appropriate key:

```
> (assoc "A" mlist :key #'car :test #'equal)
(("A" . 0) #<eql Hash Table{0} 82200283A3>)

> (assoc 0 mlist :key #'cdr)
(("A" . 0) #<eql Hash Table{0} 82200283A3>)
```